# How to work with instrument drivers and header file/static library for a new project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to work on communicating with a laser system and their instructions are very difficult to follow. I've installed the drivers and header files and static libraries on my computer and can locate them. However, I am having trouble incorporating these into Visual Studio IDE. I've tried placing the locations into the include directories but keep running into an error.

If anyone can take a look and nudge me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated, here is the link to the driver/file installation:
https://www.thorlabs.com/software/MUC/MLQ/TL_MIR_TKL_WYOA_V1.0_web-secured.pdf

I've tried including the header files and linking them by include directory in property manager but I still get an error saying cannot open include file: 'utility.h' no such file or directory

Comment: Most probably, you specified the include path incorrectly. I suggest you add a screenshot with this path and/or copy-paste all options that are passed to the compiler and linker.

Comment: I've been trying to follow the pdf and include all the files they told me to do. This is what I've included so far: https://imgur.com/a/rBQePkD

Comment: More specifically, do you know where I should be including the instrument driver. The location for the file is C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin\TLTKL_32.dll

Comment: You're doing the right thing. Are you sure it is `... (x86)` and the header is there?

Comment: You should put `TLTKL_32.lib` into `Additional Dependencies` in the `Linker` tab. DLL itself will be loaded automatically, you shouldn't include it anywhere.

Comment: Yep confirmed (x86) and there are 4 header files so I included all 4. I just can't seem to figure out what to do with the instrument driver file. Where do I put that, I've never worked with instrument drivers so genuinely confused. https://imgur.com/a/HMLm5Tj Edit: Okay so I dont' need to do anything with the DLL file.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks

Comment: You specify 1) include path for headers (`Include Directories`), 2) include path for libraries (`Library Directories`) and 3) libraries themselves (`Additional Dependencies`). Basically, that's all.

Comment: Do you know if <utility.h> and <userint.h> may be located somewhere else. I've tried browsing both of these headers and can't find anything. I've imported all the header files and libraries but keep running into issues with these two particular headers.

Comment: These are non-standard headers. Google suggest they are related to LabView.